# Is this SSD compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

I have an ASRock 970 Extreme4 (SATA 3, 6Gbps) motherboard, and wanted to know if this SSD is compatible with it:

[image: SA400S37/240G]

I know that it is usually for notebooks.
Anybody have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work just fine. Your motherboard is SATA 3 (6Gbps), and the SSD in question is SATA 3 (6Gbps) compatible. Look here:

[image]

[Here's](https://www.kingston.com/ssd/a400-solid-state-drive#specifications) the link.

Answer (score -2):

[This page](https://www.elkor.ee/en/kingston-a400-120-gb-ssd-sa400s37-120g.html) has a picture with the connectors of the SSD, which are the normal SATA connectors - it'll work just fine.

[image]